# Why doesn't grep work with single quotes?

Tags: bash, grep, string-manipulation

I have a bash script wrapped in " " so I need to use ' ' for my grep command but it doesn't work. I can't switch the quotes because then the variables are not expanded.

```
#!/bin/bash

PWD=`pwd`
source "$PWD/AWS.config.sh"

SCRIPT="
cd ~/$APP_PATH;
netstat -ln | grep ':80 ' &> /dev/null;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo something on 80;
else
    echo nothing on 80;
fi
"
ssh -i $EC2_PEM_FILE $APP_HOST $SCRIPT
```

So

```
netstat -ln | grep ':anyporthere ' &> /dev/null;
```

always seems to return $? as 0 suggesting a match when there clearly is none.

As I mentioned if I switch to " " and ' ' for the enclosing script, it works but then the script variables are not expanded which is a problem.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the inner quotes? `grep \":80 \" &> /dev/null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$?` variable in the script is being substituted when you assign the variable, not on the remote host

```
#!/bin/bash
source "$PWD/AWS.config.sh"

ssh -i "$EC2_PEM_FILE" "$APP_HOST" << END_SCRIPT
    cd ~/"$APP_PATH"
    netstat -ln | grep -q ':80 '
    if [ \$? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo something on 80
    else
        echo nothing on 80
    fi
END_SCRIPT
```

- There's already a bash variable named PWD, so you don't need to assign to it.
- Get into the habit of quoting your variables, unless you know when to not do it.
- `grep -q` is quiet but returns the same exit status. More efficient too, because it exits immediately if a match is found, not searching the rest of the file.
- do you need to `cd` just to run `netstat`?

You could also use the short-circuit boolean operators:

```
ssh -i "$EC2_PEM_FILE" "$APP_HOST" "netstat -ln | grep -q ':80 ' && echo something on 80 || echo nothing on 80"
END_SCRIPT
```

Comment: no, the cd was just to illustrate the use of variable inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by concatenating strings with differing quotes.. quite hacky though. Still prefer a nicer solution

```
SCRIPT="
blah;
blah;
"
SCRIPT+='
this grep bit " "
'

SCRIPT+="
the rest
"
```

Fugly..